# Best practice when working with double precision magic numbers

Tags: fortran

Do I necessarily need to specify `D` (e.g., `1.234D+00`) at the end of all [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) (literal constants) if I've already declared everything double precision anyway?

Comment: what do you mean by magic njmber? example?

Comment: @agentp, please see link in edit.

Comment: i guess you simply mean literal constants. The `D` is not strictly needed in case where you know the single precision representation is the same as the double. Integers for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you do.

Long answer: By default, real literals are single precision unless otherwise specified. Assigning single precision literals to double precision variables incurs precision loss; that is, single precision literals are evaluated first as single precision then assigned to the higher-precision variable. I'm too lazy to retrieve the F2003 Handbook from the other room but I suspect that single-to-double assignment sets the low significance mantissa bits to zero. Either that or it's left up to the vendor.

Regardless, here's a demonstration of what happens when you mix precision between literals and variables (note that 0.1 can't be stored cleanly in binary floating point):

```
!> Demonstrate the effects of D and E suffixes on precision of literals
program whatkind
    use iso_fortran_env, only: output_unit, REAL32, REAL64
    implicit none

    real (kind=REAL64) :: dtest

10 format('Literal ', A, ' is of kind ', I2)
20 format(/, A)
30 format(/, 'Value stored in ', A, ' precision generated with ', A,    &
          ' precision literals:')
40 format('Literal is ', A)

    continue

    write(output_unit, 10) '1.0', kind(1.0)
    write(output_unit, 10) '1.0E0', kind(1.0E0)
    write(output_unit, 10) '1.0D0', kind(1.0D0)
    write(output_unit, 10) '1.0_REAL32', kind(1.0_REAL32)
    write(output_unit, 10) '1.0_REAL64', kind(1.0_REAL64)

    write(output_unit, 20) 'Raw tenths tests:'

    dtest = 0.1
    write(output_unit, 30) 'double', 'single'
    write(output_unit, 40) '0.1'
    write(output_unit, *) dtest

    dtest = 0.1D0
    write(output_unit, 30) 'double', 'double'
    write(output_unit, 40) '0.1D0'
    write(output_unit, *) dtest

    dtest = 1.0 / 10.0
    write(output_unit, 30) 'double', 'single'
    write(output_unit, 40) '0.1'
    write(output_unit, 40) '1.0 / 10.0'
    write(output_unit, *) dtest

    dtest = 1.0_REAL64 / 10.0_REAL64
    write(output_unit, 30) 'double', 'double'
    write(output_unit, 40) '1.0_REAL64 / 10.0_REAL64'
    write(output_unit, *) dtest

    dtest = 1.0_REAL32 / 10.0_REAL32
    write(output_unit, 30) 'double', 'single'
    write(output_unit, 40) '1.0_REAL32 / 10.0_REAL32'
    write(output_unit, *) dtest

    dtest = 1.0_REAL64 / 10.0_REAL32
    write(output_unit, 30) 'double', 'mixed'
    write(output_unit, 40) '1.0_REAL64 / 10.0_REAL32'
    write(output_unit, *) dtest

    dtest = 1.0_REAL32 / 10.0_REAL64
    write(output_unit, 30) 'double', 'mixed'
    write(output_unit, 40) '1.0_REAL32 / 10.0_REAL64'
    write(output_unit, *) dtest

end program whatkind
```

The results of this are:

```
Literal 1.0 is of kind  4
Literal 1.0E0 is of kind  4
Literal 1.0D0 is of kind  8
Literal 1.0_REAL32 is of kind  4
Literal 1.0_REAL64 is of kind  8

Raw tenths tests:

Value stored in double precision generated with single precision literals:
Literal is 0.1
  0.10000000149011612     

Value stored in double precision generated with double precision literals:
Literal is 0.1D0
  0.10000000000000001     

Value stored in double precision generated with single precision literals:
Literal is 0.1
Literal is 1.0 / 10.0
  0.10000000149011612     

Value stored in double precision generated with double precision literals:
Literal is 1.0_REAL64 / 10.0_REAL64
  0.10000000000000001     

Value stored in double precision generated with single precision literals:
Literal is 1.0_REAL32 / 10.0_REAL32
  0.10000000149011612     

Value stored in double precision generated with mixed precision literals:
Literal is 1.0_REAL64 / 10.0_REAL32
  0.10000000000000001     

Value stored in double precision generated with mixed precision literals:
Literal is 1.0_REAL32 / 10.0_REAL64
  0.10000000000000001
```

You see how in cases where all the literals are single precision (including those with no explicit precision set) there is low significance 'noise' stored in the double precision variable.

I find it interesting that operations on mixed precision literals seems to promote all the literals to higher precision before the operation is performed. Someone with more language-spec-fu might be able to explain that.

My advice: When in doubt, be explicit. It's safer and I think it's worth the extra keystrokes.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Most compilers are good at catching instances of mixed precision, but I guess in this case it's left up to the programmer to make sure that all the Is are dotted and Ts are crossed.

Comment: Also, I find myself sometimes casting a single precision literal using a `KIND` parameter, as in `USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_Fortran_env, dp=>REAL64`, then `1.234_dp`. It can be nicer to look at in some cases.

Comment: My practice is to define a 'working precision' as `WP = kind(1.0D0)` but I like your method of aliasing WP to constants in `ISO_Fortran_env` better :)

Comment: A question on the _REAL32 notation: how do you combine this with scientific notation? What's the proper way to write `2.3D9_dbl` or similar?

Comment: I'd write `2.3E9_db1` just because E is the default exponent character. Using D will probably work too, but I haven't checked if it does anything weird.

Comment: On a side note: most people expect that a literal will be an IEEE binary64 floating-point number (commonly referred to as _double precision_) because they have seen similar things in C or C++. Any language needs to make a choice of what _default behaviour_ is. The Fortran standard dictates that the default behaviour is `REAL` while C and C++ dictate the default behaviour to be `double`. As a consequence, a similar strategy exist to define a literal as a `float` in those languages (`1.23f` vs `1.23`). For Fortran, what floating-point representation is connected to `REAL` is compiler dependent.